# Is it possible to get Link Relationship (XFN) field for menu item in Timber?

Tags: wordpress, timber

Couldn't find:

- Link Relationship (XFN)
- Description

Answer (score 0):

If `menu` exists in global context you can access description and xfn like

```
{% for item in menu.items %}
  {{ item.description }} - {{ item.xfn }}
{% endfor %}
```